# How to retrieve the contact number in ios 9

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7

in ios 8, i used the below code to print the user's contact Number,

```
if let contacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(self.addressBookRef)?.takeRetainedValue() as? NSArray {
            for record:ABRecordRef in contacts {

                let phones:ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeUnretainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef
                for(var numberIndex : CFIndex = 0; numberIndex < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); numberIndex++)
                {
                    let phoneUnmaganed = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, numberIndex)
                    let phoneNumber : String = phoneUnmaganed.takeUnretainedValue() as! String
```

println(phoneNumber)
                    }
                }

But apple introduced new contact framework in ios 9. Now i stuck with retrieving contact number. I found some code in the apple site and in other sites as given below, But still it's not exactly printing only the contact numbers,

```
contacts = try store.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(
                CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("Siva"),
                keysToFetch:[CNContactPhoneNumbersKey])
            for contact:CNContact in contacts {
                if (contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactPhoneNumbersKey)) {
                    for phoneNumber:CNLabeledValue in contact.phoneNumbers {
                        print(phoneNumber.value)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: please help me to retrieve all the contact number,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should do it.

```
        if (contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactPhoneNumbersKey)) {
            for phoneNumber:CNLabeledValue in contact.phoneNumbers {
                let a = phoneNumber.value as! CNPhoneNumber
                print("\(a.stringValue)")
            }
        }
```

prints in the style of
(555) 766-4823

Comment: store.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(
                CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("Siva") , i just want to fetch all the contacts. But this line of code help us to fetch only the Siva's contact details. do u have any suggestion? Thanks in advance